# Is it correct to override setter of domain property in grails?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

Is it a good idea to override setters and getters of properties in domain class? Assume we have a domain class with name property and capitalizedName where we store clean up name:

```
class Person {
    String name
    String capitalizedName

    String setName(String name){
        this.name = name
        this.searchName = name.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "").trim().toUpperCase()
    }
}
```

If I override setter and in a unit test try to use dynamic finder:

```
Person.findByName('Whatever')
```

I got

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property [name] is not a valid property of class [com.test.Person]
```

But in runtime it works pretty fine.

Can I modify getters and setters of a domain class? What is the best way to achieve behaviour as I described above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A setter should have a return type of `void`

```
 void setName(String name){
        this.name = name
        this.searchName = name.trim().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "").replaceAll(" +", " ").toUpperCase()
 }
```

Comment: I didn't expect the return type would be the cause, but I tried it out and it does matter.

Comment: Thx, didn't noticed it. Looks like codebase I have has many such problems.